# Paypal API Security header error

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal API Code integration in my project. It is working fine while using Sandbox credentials. Getting error while using Live credentials. Changed Url sandbox to Live. copied exact username, password & signature by using notepad. Still i am getting the same eoor. Can you please tell me if any changes i have to do. Searched in google but not succeded.

tested in multiple servers. getting same error in both servers.

```
 Error : Security header is not valid
 Array
(
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d05%2d01T21%3a22%3a22Z
[CORRELATIONID] => da5fb2a0d16b7
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 76%2e0
[BUILD] => 10800277
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make certain to use your Live PayPal Account Credentials and point all of your endpoints at the live PayPal Server.

User Name:
Password:
Signature:

If you attempt to use your sandbox credentials with a live endpoint you will get security header errors.

I have seen this happen simply because of the credentials not matching with the endpoint.

Here is the going live documentation from the PayPal Developer site:

[Going Live PayPal API Developer Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)

Here is a listing of PayPal Endpoints:

[PayPal Endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made mistake @ paypal.class.php file. I commented Paypal_Mode variable. now its working fine